# Is there any way to obtain the number of iterations the program did with scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm referring to the parameter `maxfev`, which tells us the number of iterations. Is there any to have this number after a fit is done?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using scipy v1.9 or greater, you can set the keyword argument `full_output=True`. In this case the third value in the `curve_fit`'s output will be `infodict` - a dictionary in which the key `nfev` gives the number of function calls that have been performed in the calculation. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for more information.

Comment: Definitively useful, although the number of function calls can be very different from the number of iterations.